# Squeezing shape by another one

Tags: physics, collision

I'm trying to simulate the growth of a cancer in the blood vessels in Blender 2.78c. Firstly, I created the network of blood vessels using [this addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61522). Then, I created a simulation of the cancer with the UV Sphere growing in time (using keyframes on the *Scale* property). The problem is that this growing ball penetrates through the blood vessels, while I want to simulate the collision between the growing cancer and the blood vessels, which results in something like squeezing these vessels.

After some research I think that the blood vessels should be modified by the *Soft Body*, while the growing sphere should be modified by the *Collision*, but I'm still not able to simulate the collision between these two objects.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0pxb2zus69uap59/Projekt.blend?dl=0) is my blendfile without any Physics. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the goal is to show the blood vessels change position with the growth of the cancer, this answer might be useful - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70151/how-to-animate-a-beating-heart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not at all a "physically accurate" simulation by any stretch, but it may be able to approximate the desired effect with a bunch of modifier trickery using a *Vertex Weight Proximity* and a *Cast* modifier.

[image]

Use the *Vertex Weight Proximity* to make a vertex group weight vary according to the distance to a random object, in this case a "cancer ball", then use said vertex group to drive the influence of a *Cast* modifier set to *Sphere*.

You can then dynamically adjust the size of the "cancer sphere" (and shape too) to influence the distortion of the blood vessels

[image]

Comment: That's enough for my needs. Thank you very much for the detailed tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Lattice to deform the mesh. Otherwise you could try parenting the mesh to an object then deforming the parent.