# How to achieve a 3D warp field effect in blender (2.81)

Tags: effects

I'm after a way to create an effect such that when an object is placed inside the volume the verticies are displaced based on the localised field value (thinking of it like a density field in physics where the local distance between atoms decreases as density value of a region increases)?

The current model I would like to use it on is spiral column that I need to gradually flare out at the top and displace randomly along its length in order to create a solid tornado funnel - but I'm sure I could come up with lots of uses once I know how to do it.

Comment: Vertex Proximity Weight might do what you are looking for https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin/153181#153181 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165827/using-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve-to-raise-lower-height-of-vertices/165831#165831

Comment: Is this the effect your are looking for? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84438/squeezing-shape-by-another-one/84460#84460

Comment: While the proximity weight modifier looks very interesting it wasn't exactly what I wanted - but while looking at other answers to the suggested questions I found the Lattice Modifier which is pretty much exactly what I was thinking of just by a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I finally found out about the Lattice modifier system which when you take away the physics speak is exactly what I was thinking of when I posted the original question - below is a proof of concept 'Tornado Susan' using the stock Susan model with a lattice modifier applied to flare the top and give the length a bit of a flick[image: Tornado Susan]
And the [Lattice Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html) that was applied is shown below which takes no time using proportional editing[image: Deformation Latice]