# How to Make flower petals compressed INSIDE a Sphere

Tags: modifiers, particles, displacement, geometry-nodes

i want to make  flower petals compressed INSIDE a Sphere.
just like this image.
i just want the petals inside , not the sphere part nor the upper part
[image: The Result a want]

Comment: Perhaps the opposite of this technique https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84438/squeezing-shape-by-another-one/84460#84460

Comment: You can use shrinkwrap modifier with inside mode. play with the offset value.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an option with a zero-gravity  *Cloth* simulation.

First, lazy modeling of these flower petals inside:

- create a plane and subdivide it a few times. That's the flower petal instance.
- create a tiny sphere and add 20 hair particles.
- set the *Particle Settings > Render > Render As* to `Object` and  *Particle Settings > Render > Instance Object* to the plane.

Now create one single object from this and make it cloth:

- convert the particles to a mesh (modifier tab).
- join all flower petals to one mesh object (select all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
- add a *Cloth* modifier
- turn off *Gravity*. It's in *Cloth Settings > Field Weights*.
- turn on *Self Collision*.

Then model an oversized cherry (Icoshphere, a little editing & *Subdivision Surface* modifier).

- add a *Collision* and a *Soldify* modifier to it.

Last but not least, make a short shrink animation by keyframing the scale value of the cherry (<kbd>I</kbd> in *Object* mode). Run the simulation. If you're happy with the result apply the *Cloth* modifier.

[image: cloth sim]

Test render:
[image: test render]

Comment: Man, that result is really beautiful, well done :))

Comment: just great!!!!!!!!! +1