# 3-Dimensional Voronoi Mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, 3d-printing

I'm trying to create a 3-dimensional voronoi mesh as packaging for a 3D-printed ceramic part. I want to print it with a rubber like material to absorb against shocks.
I imagine a Strukture with a relative open outer shell and a dense core around the ceramic part.

My best attempt so far was creating the packaging and subracting the space that has to be left free for the ceramic part using the boolean-modifier.
then I added a particle system to the ceramic part and removed gravity in order to let them spread in all directions uniformily (more particles closer to the centre).
Based on these particles I used the Cell-Fracture-Tool where I removed the margin. After that I used limmited dissole and remove doubles to get rid of unecessary geometry.

Unfortunaly the skin modifier takes ages on my pc and the level of complexity so I couldn't get it to work/adjust it properly.
My other guess was to convert the mesh to a curve and give it a thickness. This works pretty well but I would like to get the corners just a little bit rounder and organic, but the subdivison modifier leads to a "stringy" resoult.

test without sudivision:
[image: (edgy test)]

test with sudivision:
[image: (example with sudivision modifier)]

Does anybody know other ways to make a mesh with the features described where I have more controll over the resoult?
Help for a more uniform look of the resoult (is there a way to make particles speed up or to controll the way they spread -> like a dodecaeder grid?), or just how i controll the edges would be greatly appreciated!

P.S.: The object in the picures is just a Ico-Sphere inside a Cube!

Comment: Look into the "tissue" addon

Comment: How would that help me out with a 3-dimensional voronoi mesh? As far as I see this just wraps mashes around the object and doesnt realy affect the inside or am I wrong?

Comment: I wonder if you could get the addon Tissue to work for you? http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue

Comment: Also have you seen this video of a voronoi mesh generated from surface fractures? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ge-EKxWPy2Q It is printed at the end as well, but its just a surface shape not a structured volume. Perhaps you could use a particle system in a volume with a voronoi texture effector? Then convert the particle paths with another addon?

Comment: that comes close to what I have done. But the problem Is that this methode gives a very angular look. I had hoped to make it more smooth but if you use a subdivision modifier you get that "stringy" resoult shown above. Could you recommend any suited particle addon?

Comment: Oooh just saw this new approach using Sverchock addon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux9DrhxeCU0 Still angular but there may be tools to vary that. Ask the video author for tips.

Comment: Did you ever manage to do this? Im trying the same thing. You could add your solution as your own answer for instance.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: use wireframe modifier and a subdivision modifier.

Blender 2.9 instructions

**Step 1: particle system**

[image: particle system settings]

[image: particle system]

**Step 2: Cell fracture**

Enable the add-on cell fracture

[image: cell fracture]

Hit okay

[image: fractured]

**Step 3: Joining**

select new pieces

[image: selection]

Join

[image: joined]

In edit mode, merge nearby verts:

[image: merge by distance]

**Step 4: Wireframe**

Add wireframe modifier (disable Even Thickness)

[image: wireframe modifier]

Add remesh modifier with voxels in order to repair broken geometry from wireframe modifier

[image: remesh]

**Step 5: smoothen**

Add decimate modifier to simplify geometry

[image: decimate]

Add subdivision modifier to smooth the surface

[image: smoothing]

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about making a simple mesh and then using the *Wireframe Modifier*? It might give better control and hopefully pack the object securely...

[image]

Comment: No, actually not because it isn't the desired effect. It shouldn't be "just" packaging but also a little piece of art. Also the model I am trying to contain in it is a little more complex and it would be a pain to do it all by hand. I have seen a lot of voronoi that is just a "skin" or a "cage" like yours. But I need the "infill" too, not just because of the visual effect, but for protection of the product. thank you a lot for your comment!

Comment: There are some answers to another question that might be of interest https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61261/techniques-for-modeling-a-network-of-blood-vessels Good luck with your endeavor.