# Fill in object with procedural shader, like vessels in human body

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, modifiers, shaders, procedural

I’m trying to achieve in Blender Cycles (preferably 2.79b) a shader that fills in any object with procedural generation.

For example, if I have a model of a hand, I want to fill with vessels inside the hand. Like following inage:

[image: Vessels in hand]

My final goal is not to add vessels, but tree branches/roots. I want to make a hand look like it’s made out of tree roots. Or maybe electronic wires.

I think is the same idea, but different settings on how the inner object renders.

Here is another example, but being used in a human lung: (Apparently this was made in Houdini)

[image: Houdini lung vessels]

Can anyone lead me to the right path to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello :). This already has an amazing answer somewhere here on SE, I just cannot find it right now...

Comment: I've found it! https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/61261/78972

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ Will check it out! Thank you!